# select data from MySQL programmatically

Tags: php, mysql

I have table in MySQL where the data are stored like:

```
table_1 
+-------+-------+  
|field_0|field_1|
+-------+-------+  
| WCON  |  A    |
+-------+-------+
| KROGR |  B    |
+-------+-------+
|       |  C    |
+-------+-------+
| HALL  |  D    |
+-------+-------+
| OZARK |  E    |
+-------+-------+
|       |  F    |
+-------+-------+
| MAR   |  G    |
+-------+-------+
| KROGR |  H    |
+-------+-------+
| MAR   |  I    |
+-------+-------+
```

there are some field with empty value in field_0.

my code runs in php. there is a dropdown menu where all the field names are put manually and the values in the menu are " all | WCON | KROGR | HALL | OZARK |MAR ". From the dropdown menu if "MAR" is selected it will show G and I, but when "all" is selected it need to show all values of field_1.

My code is like that

```
$field_value = "MAR";
$query = "select field_1 from table_1 where field_0 = '$field_value ' ";
```

but how can I select all values using the $field_value variable ??

Comment: Not sure if I'm understanding your question correctly your query will give you all values in field_1 e.g. in your example G and I

Comment: Is that your real code or did you retype it here? You miss-spelled field_1 in your query (reads filed_1)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Only add the WHERE clause if the `$field_value` is not 'all'. Also, make sure you sanitize any user input into a query. Even if it comes from a dropdown, if the value is being passed to the page from another page, users could be able to insert bad values there.

```
$query = "SELECT field_1 FROM table_1";

if ($field_value != "all")
  $query .= " WHERE field_0 = '". mysql_real_escape_string($field_value) ."'";
```

Answer (score -1):

add the php variable in the sql like this:

```
mysql_query("
SELECT DISTINCT 
c.id AS courseid, 
".$entityString.", 
c.fullname,
c.shortname, 
c.startdate, 
u.id as userid, 

FROM mdl_course c
join mdl_course_categories ct on ct.id = c.category

".$whereClause." AND rl.id = 5 ".$orderClause."
");
```

Notice  ".$entityString." ,  ".$whereClause." and ".$orderClause." are all variables.